# How to use RDD persist and cache?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Please tell me how to use RDD methods Persist() and Cache(), it seems for a conventional program which i usually write in java, Say for sparkStreaming, which is a continues execution of DAG, where every time the value of RDD will get updated and hence perist/cache will also be called again & again and will result in overwriting that RDD.

But as the documentation shows below, it seems like these methods are useful for the interactive shells only or is there any way i can use the cached/persist RDD in my sequential program more efficiently in comparison to merely storing the desired RDD in any reference variable.

**[Spark Doc Link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching)**

```
scala> linesWithSpark.cache()
res7: spark.RDD[String] = spark.FilteredRDD@17e51082

scala> linesWithSpark.count()
res8: Long = 19

scala> linesWithSpark.count()
res9: Long = 19
```

**VS**

In a sequential spark-streaming job i think this is very same and will not be evaluated again and again.

```
JavaRDD sortedRDD =baseRDD.filter(f(x));

sortedRDD.count();
sortedRDD.saveAsNewHadoopAPIFile();
// Or Anything we want !
```

I would be grateful if you can help in resolving this doubt.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important capabilities in Spark is persisting (or caching) a dataset in memory across operations. When you persist an RDD, each node stores any partitions of it that it computes in memory and reuses them in other actions on that dataset (or datasets derived from it). This allows future actions to be much faster (often by more than 10x). Caching is a key tool for iterative algorithms and fast interactive use.
You can mark an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache() methods on it. The first time it is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes. Spark’s cache is fault-tolerant – if any partition of an RDD is lost, it will automatically be recomputed using the transformations that originally created it.
The cache() method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY (store deserialized objects in memory).

```
val linesWithSpark  = sc.textFile("/home/kishore/test.txt")
linesWithSpark.cache()
linesWithSpark.count()
```

It does nothing. RDD.cache is also a lazy operation. The file is still not read. But now the RDD says "read this file and then cache the contents". If you then run linesWithSpark.count the first time, the file will be loaded, cached, and counted. If you call linesWithSpark.count a second time, the operation will use the cache. It will just take the data from the cache and count the lines.

Comment: In pyspark v 2.1.1 , I think cache needs to be assigned. e.g. ```linesWithSpark = linesWithSpark.cache()```. The example as given above did not speed up repeated counts.

Answer (score 1):

Both caching and persisting are used to save the Spark RDD, Dataframe and Dataset’s. But, the difference is, RDD `cache()` method default saves it to memory (**MEMORY_ONLY**) whereas `persist()` method is used to store it to user-defined storage level.

When you persist a dataset, each node stores it’s partitioned data in memory and reuses them in other actions on that dataset. And Spark’s persisted data on nodes are fault-tolerant meaning if any partition of a Dataset is lost, it will automatically be recomputed using the original transformations that created it.

Spark `cache()` method in Dataset class internally calls `persist()` method which in turn uses **sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery** to cache the result set of DataFrame or Dataset.

```
 import spark.implicits._

val columns = Seq("Seqno","Quote")
  val data = Seq(("1", "Be the change that you wish to see in the world"),
    ("2", "Everyone thinks of changing the world, but no one thinks of changing himself."),
    ("3", "The purpose of our lives is to be happy."))
  val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

  val dfCache = df.cache()
  dfCache.show(false)
```

Spark `persist` has two signature first signature doesn’t take any argument which by default saves it to **MEMORY_AND_DISK** storage level and the second signature which takes *StorageLevel* as an argument to store it to different storage levels.

```
val dfPersist = df.persist()
dfPersist.show(false)
```

Using second signature you can save DataFrame/Dataset to One of storage levels **MEMORY_ONLY,MEMORY_AND_DISK, MEMORY_ONLY_SER, MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, DISK_ONLY, MEMORY_ONLY_2,MEMORY_AND_DISK_2**

```
val dfPersist = df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
dfPersist.show(false)
```

Let me know if this helps.